# Sorting Cell Array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, cell-array

I have a cell array 5x1 contains directories of 5 image files like:

```
C:\Program Files\file1.jpg
C:\Program Files\file5.jpg
C:\Program Files\file2.jpg
```

and so on

The order of the files is missed up. How can I sort this cell array?
for example:

```
file1.jpg
file2.jpg
```

and so on

Thanks!

Comment: Tried with `sort` yet?!

Comment: As I said, this is exactly what [sort](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) does. Have you even tried to google this?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = {'C:\Program Files\file1.jpg';...
     'C:\Program Files\file5.jpg';...
     'C:\Program Files\file2.jpg'};
b = sort(a)
```

Comment: @Dani The example I posted _does_ work, respectively does what it is supposed to do: After running it, b is the alphabetically sorted version of a (note that a is still unsorted). Please provide further information what exactly does not work, respectively what you exactly want.